# How to run TestCases for 32-Bit build only on TFS server

Tags: winforms, unit-testing, tfs, 32bit-64bit

I have written some Testcases in C# using Microsoft unit test framework and some of the TC needs some drivers to create new Database files. Now we can install either 32-Bit or 64-Bit driver on one machine. 
Now these TC automatically run for both 32-bit and 64-bit configuration on TFS server, which contains drivers installed for 32-bit only.
So now for 64-bit build, it is failing and I am unable to checkIn the code.

Is there any attribute (like TestClass, TestInitialize) or any configuration in the .proj file which we can do so that those TC will run only for 32-build and not for 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Just try below ways:

1.Build the x86 and x64 builds separately, run test for x86 build.

2.Create `.runsettings` file and specify
   `<TargetPlatform>x86</TargetPlatform>`, then use the `.runsettings`
   file for the testing.

3.Create two `runsettings` files, one for x86 and one for x64.  Specify the platform there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <!-- Configurations that affect the Test Framework -->
  <RunConfiguration>
    <!-- [x86] | x64  
      - You can also change it from menu Test, Test Settings, Default Processor Architecture -->
    <TargetPlatform>x86</TargetPlatform>
    <!-- Framework35 | [Framework40] | Framework45 -->
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>Framework40</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

Reference below articles:

- [Configure unit tests by using a .runsettings file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx)
- [Run a unit test as a 64-bit process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee782531.aspx)

[image]